# Error HE0018: Could not launch the simulator application: The application “Simulator” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I am using Visual studio 2019 for mac
iOS 15.4
Xcode 13.3

When I try to run any Xamarin iOS project it gives me the "Error HE0018: Could not launch the simulator application: The application “Simulator” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred." and there are no other logs/ errors.

Can anyone help me out ?

Thanking you in Advance!!

Note : The projects were running on previous OS versions

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this using Xcode 13.3 and recent updates to VS.8.10.23(build 4)
I've been able to work through this particular error by

1. Setting up an empty project in Xcode.
2. Selecting the desired simulator
3. Build and run in Xcode with desired simulator
4. If that works, switch over to Visual Studio and select the same simulator and you should be able to attach the debugger to it and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

I just test on my mac it works fine , here are some suggestions for you

1. Update `Xcode(13.3)` and `Visual Studio(8.10.21)` to the latest.
2. Check all the third-party plugins to ensure all of them support `iOS 15.4` .
3. Open Xcode and run an iOS project to ensure the simulator works as expected.

If problem persists , try to reinstall Xcode and VS for mac and reboot your mac .

Answer (score 0):

In my case the simulator also stayed black when running a small Xcode project.

Clear the simulator solved the issue:
Go to Simulator and open "Device" menu and choose "Erase All Content and Settings..."